# How do i write a SQL while loop to check rows in multiple databases with similar name, but with different archive numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a `WHILE` loop in SQL Server with a `varchar` variable.

This works

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 18;

WHILE @counter >= 14
BEGIN
    PRINT @counter;
    SET @counter = @counter - 1
END
```

But I really want is a while loop that would go through each of these archives, check to see if they have any rows, and if they're empty, keep going until it finds a row in one or until a specified archive number. I've tried using cursor, but can't seem to figure this one. Thank you.

```
DatabaseArchive20
DatabaseArchive19
DatabaseArchive18
DatabaseArchive17
```

This is what I've tried.

Here's an example I've been trying to work with.

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 18
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR (1000)

WHILE @counter >= 14
BEGIN
    SET @counter = @counter - 1
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM [DatabaseArchive' + @counter + '].[dbo].[Feeds] WHERE AccNum = 123456'
    PRINT @sql
END
```

I'm getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT * FROM [DatabaseArchive' to data type int

Comment: Your question is far too broad for us to give an answer. However, I'd start with [Aaron Bertrand's](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) proc for executing whatever code you want in each database. If you're set on `WHILE` loops then the [documentation will help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @scsimon

I appreciate your reply, i'm still an amateur, but i edited my question to be a bit more clearer. Could you please take a second look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for editing your question.

You are getting the error because SQL Server is trying to *add* your @counter (as in arithmetic) instead of *concatenate* it to your string. To prevent this error, you need to `cast` or `convert` it into a `varchar`.

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 18
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR (1000)
WHILE @counter >= 14
BEGIN
SET @counter = @counter-1
SET @sql= 'SELECT * FROM [DatabaseArchive'+cast(@counter as varchar(2))+'].[dbo].[Feeds] WHERE 
AccNum=123456'
PRINT @sql
END
```

I would still suggest using [Aaron Bertrand's Proc](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: @marc_s Great point though for 18, or even an insanely large number of databases for the OP, this wouldn't be an issue since it wouldn't truncate in the cast. Correct?

Comment: Right - for converting an `INT`, the current default length of 30 is plenty enough. It's just more about the principle of always specifying a length - because in other cases, the default is just **1 character** and that might trip you up, if you don't pay attention to it ....